# Chunks not connected

Tags: python, perlin-noise

Here is my code:

```
def generate(octaves):
    global world, xpix, chunkSize #set globals (for other references in the rest of the script etc)
    chunkSize = (12, 12)
    xpix, ypix = chunkSize[0], chunkSize[1]
    world = []
    noise1 = PerlinNoise(octaves=octaves, seed=seed) #make noise
    
    for i in range(xpix): # make list for drawer to use
        row = []
        for j in range(ypix):
            noise_val = noise1([(i / xpix) + chunkCoordX * xpix, (j / ypix) + chunkCoordY * ypix])

            if noise_val <= .05:
                tiletoplace = tileclassdata.water
            elif noise_val <= .13:
                tiletoplace = tileclassdata.sand
            else:
                tiletoplace = tileclassdata.grass
            placed_tile = classes.tile(tiletoplace, i, j)
            row.append(placed_tile)
        world.append(row)
```

I am trying to make the chunks I generate connect. For example:

I could have a chunk at 1,-4 and one at 0,-4. But this is what they'd look like:

[image: Chunk at 1,-4]

[image: Chunk at 0, -4]

I would like them to connect so that I can get things like islands generating across chunks instead of just have random blobs scattered around my game's map.

I have tried refactoring the sum for working out the chunks position in the perlin-noise map but I have not been able to devise a sum that figures it out.

Comment: what is the purpose of `global` and why the indentation of the rest of the code ?  this code will not work.

Comment: please amend the syntax errors in the code so
that other users can reproduce the problem quickly:
[minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Sorry for the confusing code sample. The problems should be fixed now.

Comment: for a small fraction of tiles selected at random (say, 1/16th), generate a number coming from a distribution (normal, lognormal, etc). Then, smooth things out with a rather large window (say, 8x8 for every 16th tile). As a result, you'll get an island-ish landscape

Comment: Could you expand further? E.g. code samples and explaining how to do this? (Sorry if I'm asking a lot, I'm new to this more complex stuff)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick and dirty example of the idea in the comments:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import ndimage
import seaborn as sns

def generate_landscape(field_size: int, flatness: int, magnitude=255):
    """ Generates an islandish landscape, given:

    Args:
        field_size: size of the resulting numpy array
        flatness: very large number will result in a completely flat terrain;
            1 will result in every spot being drawn at random
    """
    field = np.random.binomial(1, 1 / flatness, size=(field_size, field_size)) \
        * np.random.randint(low=0, high=magnitude, size=(field_size, field_size))
    mask_size = max(int(flatness ** 0.5), 1)
    return ndimage.gaussian_filter(field, mask_size)

sns.heatmap(generate_landscape(32, 10))
```

Example output:

[image]

After that, I'd take a desired water/sand %%, calculate quantiles and apply the threshold.